# CSS: How do I get the nav to work if it's positioned inside the image

Tags: html, css, navigation, css-selectors, background-image

I'm a CSS novice in need of some help. I need to display a header image and have a working dropdown nav menu sit inside the bottom right of the image. I went ahead and created the nav and used a negative margin to position it so that it appears at the bottom of the background image. The hover effect in the nav is clearly not working. And it has to do with it being inside the image. So how do I get the nav to work if it's positioned inside the image? Or is there a better way to display the nav in the image's bottom right? Thank you for your help!

Here's the code:

```css
.img {
  background-image: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bfoley-teamug/misc_images/master/section_header_ip.png");
  min-height: 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  float: right;
  margin: -40px 0;
}

#topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#topnav a {
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="img">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div id="topnav">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with an image from for example placeholder.com

Comment: ok, I've added the image, thanks!

Comment: Remove `position: relative;` then the image is not overlaying the links

Comment: @mplungjan that's it, thank you!